# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function set_magic_quotes_runtime()

Tags: php, joomla

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function set_magic_quotes_runtime()

The above  error occur while installing joomla 1.5.15

Comment: Please check php verion or talk to hosting provider

Comment: Since PHP 5.3 this function has been deprecated and will raise an E_DEPRECATED warning upon execution. Since PHP 5.4 this function will also raise an E_CORE_ERROR on trying to enable magic quotes. http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-magic-quotes-runtime.php

Comment: Support for Joomla 1.5 ended in 2012 so you should seriously consider upgrading...

Comment: undefined means , undefined simple

Comment: The developers of the software often make updates. You can install their newest version, and it shall be without this warning.